# XCode's Documentation Complains "File Not Found" but Gives Correct Results

Tags: xcode

When I'm searching for something in the Developer Documentation of Xcode, I constantly get "File not Found"/"The requested file was not found in any documentation set."

The odd thing is, it still works.  E.g., if I search for NSSound, I can find NSSound.

The error dialogue is invoked whenever it attempts to search as I type, which makes it particularly annoying.

This only happens when I select certain documentation sets (e.g., "iPhone OS 3.1 Library").  I tried deleting it & re-installing, but the same result.  (Perhaps I didn't remove everything?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put up a post to fix this over here:
http://allens-techlog.blogspot.com/2009/11/fixing-xcode-requested-file-was-not.html

Answer (score 1):

Another fix is to change your searching from "All Doc Sets" to "Apple iPhone OS 3.1". Once you've done that, select the "Apple iPhone OS 3.0" docset. Although it's old you won't get the error and in a month or two you can change it back.

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring again with Xcode 5+ and Mavericks doc sets. For example:

> The requested file cannot be found:
>   /var/folders/l5/g1r3n28s1v38t5ntjqb_1dq80000gn/T/xcdocui.css.

When it appears try in this order:

1. Restart Xcode
2. Log out / log in
3. Restart

If you don't want to log out or restart, you can delete the temporary parent folder of the CSS file that cannot be found (T stands for 'temporary'), then quit and restart Xcode. But note this will also delete temporary files other running apps might be using, so you might get similar "file cannot be found" messages from other apps, until they are also restarted. Also see [this](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2013/Oct/msg00141.html) Apple Mailing List post.

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem even in Mavericks and Xcode5, almost 5 years later!

Here's maybe a less scary method than just deleting the rather populated "T" directory:

- get out of Xcode. Try not to do anything else either, (who knows what else writes in T?),
  but quit Xcode at least.
- navigate to the /var/folders/...whatever.../T/.. directory (parent of T)
- hide it temporarily with
  mv T xT
- start up Xcode
- look at some doc just to be sure
- quit Xcode
- look at that same dir; a new T will be there with xcdocui.css in it
- cp T/xcdocui.css xT/xcdocui.css
- swap it back quickly  with rm -rf T ; mv xT T
- restart Xcode and see if it works.
- "It works for me"

This .css file is kind of small and boring to be causing such a fuss!

Answer (score 0):

That was your early Thanksgiving treat from Apple. They sent a docset 3.1 "update" out about 4-5 days ago and F'ed up alot of peoples documentation. It's basically unusable for me right now...I can't do anything without having do dismiss a never-ending barage of "page not found" error dialogs. It also trashed 50% of the favorites links I had on the left panel of documents. I assume these were from the docsets it now want's me to re-subscribe to but gives an error every time I try.

Haven't seen alot of posts about it yet so I would bet that Apple will likely do nothing. If it were possible to get a human on the phone over there I would have some answers to go along with the frustration.

Happy Thanksgiving

PS. Best to turn OFF the auto-update option in documentation. If not for having that option ON I'd currently be oblivious to this issue and capable of viewing my documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this as well. I am guessing it is not affecting very many people though, since searching "the requested file was not found in any documentation set" in google is still only turning up four hits. And it is affecting my desktop but not my laptop.

Have either of you tried reinstalling Xcode?